# Что такое двумерный синтаксис в контексте Haskell?

Tags: haskell, синтаксис

Примерно я понимаю что это такое, но не могу придумать определение, которое сгодилось для его описания.

Если существует, приведите перевод этого термина на англ. язык.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перевод этого термина на английский: *layout* или *layout based syntax*. К сожалению, слово layout очень перегружено, поэтому искать по нему сложно.

Что же до определения: какого рода определение вы хотите сформулировать?

Я бы сформулировал что-то вроде такого

layout based syntax - это такой вид синтаксиса, при котором неоднозначности трактовки исходного кода разрешаются за счёт его специального форматирования с помощью отступов.